# Why is my S3 lifecycle policy not taking effect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 lifecycle policy to delete objects after 3 days, and I am using a prefix. My problem is that the policy works for all but one sub-directory. For example, lets say my bucket looks like this:

`s3://my-bucket/myPrefix/env=dev/`

`s3://my-bucket/myPrefix/env=stg/`

`s3://my-bucket/myPrefix/env=prod/`

When I check the stg and prod directories, there are no objects older than 3 days. However, when I check the dev directory, there are objects a lot older than that.

**Note** - There is a huge difference between the volume of data in dev compared to the other 2. Dev holds a lot more logs than the others.

My initial thought was that it was taking longer for Eventual Consistency to show what was deleted and what wasn't, but that theory is gone considering the time that has passed.

The issue seems related to the amount of data in this location under the prefix compared to the others, but I'm not sure what I can do to resolve this. Should I have another policy specific to this location, or is there a somewhere I can check to see what is causing the failure? I did not see anything in Cloudtrail for this event.

Here is my policy:

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Expiration": {
                "Days": 3
            },
            "ID": "Delete Object When Stale",
            "Prefix": "myPrefix/",
            "Status": "Enabled"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you have only the single rule (shown above)? If so, it should behave the same across all sub-folders. You could experiment by adding another sub-folder and see whether it works. Otherwise, it sounds like a case for AWS Support.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein I am indeed saying I have 1 single rule, and I expected it to act the same across all sub-folders. I was hoping it wasn't a support issue, but looks like it.

Comment: I don't think it's eventual consistency per se, but potentially the expiration is taking some time actually churning through the "huge difference."  What do you see in the bucket logs?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot bucket logging is not enabled and CLoudtrail does not show anything for this bucket, except the manual lifecycle policy change